# Controlling visibility of elements related to prop items in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Pretty new to Vue and still trying to understand the principals.

I'm trying to create a custom component that takes a hierarchical list of items and displays them in a flat list. I want to be able to hide and show each item based on a click event. It's basically a customized tree component. I'm struggling to implement this behavior.

What I tried was to create a computed property that adds an `isVisible` attribute to each item and in the template bind `show` directive to this attribute. But this doesn't work as computed properties are not reactive and any attribute I add is not being watched.

I feel like this should be pretty simple and I'm not getting Vue basics. Options I could think of are:

1- Add an `isVisible` attribute to each item through `Vue.set()`.

2- Keep a list of visible items in a data object.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

What I tried regarding the first method is below, which doesn't render any items in the list and I get Vue warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "isVisible" is not defined on the 
instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this 
property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class- 
based components, by initializing the property. See: 
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive- 
Properties.

<template>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="(header,col) in headers" :key="col" >
                <td> {{ header.name }} </td>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <template v-for="item in flat_items">
            <tr v-show="isVisible" v-bind:key="item.id">
                <td v-for="(header,id) in headers" :item="item" :key="header.id">
                    <template v-if="item.children && id==0"> 
                        <v-icon>chevron_right</v-icon> 
                    </template>
                    {{ item[header.value] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    name: 'table-tree',
    props: [
        'items',
        'headers'
    ],
    data: function() {
        return {
            ui_item_props : {
                isVisible: true
            },
        }
    },  
    methods: {
        flatten : function(arr, parent_id) {
            var a = [];
            var arrLength = arr.length;
            for (var i=0;i<arrLength;i++) {
                var children = arr[i].children;
                var item = arr[i]
                a.push({...item, parent:parent_id})
                if(Array.isArray(children)){
                    a = a.concat(this.flatten(children,item.id))
                }
            }
            return a
        },
        addPropsObj : function(obj,props) {
            var k;
            for (k in props){
                this.$set(obj,k,props[k])
            }
        },
        addPropsRec : function(arr, props) {
            var arrLength=arr.length
            for(var i=0;i<arrLength;i++){
                this.addPropsObj(arr[i], props);
                if(Array.isArray(arr[i].children)){
                    this.addPropsRec(arr[i].children, props)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        flat_items : function() {
            return this.flatten(this.items,null)
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.addPropsRec(this.items,this.ui_item_props)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you create a seperate component for the row items (e.g. `<rowItem />`). That component has an `isVisible` property in the data function which can be set to true and false via a button in that same component. Then, in your main component, loop over flat_items and pass item as a prop to that component like `<template v-for="item in flat_items"> <rowItem :item="item"  v-bind:key="item.id" /></template>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "isVisible" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this  property
> is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-  based
> components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-
> Properties.

This error is self-explanatory, you had not created the isVisible property but you are using it inside the template.
But adding only the isVisible property inside your `data/computed object`, will not solve your problem.
What you can do is to add a `isVisible` property per each element in your `flat_items` array and then use that variable inside the v-show:

```
<tr v-show="item.isVisible" v-bind:key="item.id">
```

Then you have to manage the state of your object visibility, something like:

```
 <v-icon @click="manageVisibility(item)">chevron_right</v-icon>
```

And inside your javascript:

```
manageVisibility(item) {
    Vue.set(item, 'isVisible', !item.isVisible);
}
```

Comment: I thought I did exactly what you suggested but I realized that I made the dumb mistake of referring the variable as `isVisible` instead of `item.isVisible`.